# How to import maked javafx jar file into scene builder?

Tags: javafx, jar, scenebuilder

I've developting [custom control. Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy11D.jpg). I complete making this control.

And then. I wanted to use it in scene builder. So, I export my file to jar. And I import jar file in Scene builder.

But, Scene builder [print noting. Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysfxG.jpg)

First of all my struecture is like this. One control match One skin.

```
sample
    control
        DateChooser.java
        DateChooserSkin.java
        DatePickerForm.java
        DatePickerFormSkin.java
    css
         ....
    image
         ....
    fxml 
         sample.fxml
    Main.java
```

I have  two control. So, the result is Like this UI is consist of one textFeild and one datePciker.

I wrote fxml code and Main. java like this.

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="240.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
     <DatePickerForm></DatePickerForm>
</AnchorPane>


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I was proceed exporting jar.

Choose Main method and I exported. and then I just put this jar to Scene builder. But The result is terrible.

What is wrong? Please Help me.

My error log is this

xception for: sample/DateChooser.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: sample.DateChooser

```
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)

at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)

... 11 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sample.DateChooser.()

```
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)

... 13 more
```

Exception for: sample/DateChooserSkin.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: sample.DateChooserSkin

```
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)

at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)

... 11 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sample.DateChooserSkin.()

```
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)

... 13 more
```

Exception for: sample/DatePickerForm.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = LibraryFolderWatcher(C:\Users\GSD\AppData\Roaming\Scene Builder/Library)

```
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:210)

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:393)

at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:374)

at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:232)

at javafx.scene.Scene$3$1.<init>(Scene.java:436)

at javafx.scene.Scene$3.createPopupScene(Scene.java:436)

at com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.createPopupScene(SceneHelper.java:59)

at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:142)

at javafx.stage.Popup.<init>(Popup.java:39)

at sample.DatePickerForm.<init>(DatePickerForm.java:32)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)

at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)

... 8 more
```

Exception for: sample/DatePickerFormSkin.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: sample.DatePickerFormSkin

```
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)

at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)

... 11 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sample.DatePickerFormSkin.()

```
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)

... 13 more
```

Not a Node: sample/Main.class

Comment: and My error log is this

Comment: I think the `scene builder` only handles the `FXML` custom components (i'm not sure) !

Comment: Is your custom component open-sourced? If yes, can you add a link to its source?

Comment: https://github.com/rlawlstjd0077/CustomDateTimePickerFX

Comment: My source is this.